# how to stop a button from being fired when press enter

Tags: javascript, button, click, keycode

I am using this function to handle enter click on a search textbox but it fires another button in the page, how to stop that button from being fired and call my search() function.

```
InputKeyPress(e) {
    if (window.event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            search();
        }
    } else {
        if (e) {
           if (e.which == 13) {
               search();
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `keyCode == 13` case, you need to prevent the default action of the `keypress` event. The standard way to do this is to call the `preventDefault` function on the event object (if it has one; it doesn't on earlier versions of IE). The older way is to return `false` from your event handler function. There's no real harm in a "belt and braces" approach of doing both. :-)

You can also shorten your function a bit:

```
function InputKeyPress(e) {
    var keyCode;

    e = e || window.event;
    keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        search();
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "return false" like this:

```
function InputKeyPress(e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        search();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And also change the call from the textbox to this:

```
<input .... onkeypress="return InputKeyPress(event);" ...>
```

Meaning not just call the function but "return" it.

Comment: Thanx dear u really helped :) we are launching and that bug was driving me crazy

Comment: @Miroo no problem, please mark one of the (pretty same) answers as correct. :)