# Two buttons are getting fired by a single press of enter key

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am working in IE8. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div onkeypress =handleEnter()>
      name <input  type="text" src='Create.gif' >
      </br>
      <input  type="image" src='Create.gif' onclick="alert('not done')">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function handleEnter()
    {
      if(window.event.keyCode==13)
      {
        alert('nothing');
        event.cancelBubble=true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

This is just a sample code, but my problem is that whenever I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key both alert boxes are coming that indicates that create button is also clicked. I want to prevent it for a greater cause in my code.

Comment: Perhaps look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237032/how-to-stop-a-button-from-being-fired-when-press-enter

Same issue.

Comment: Please indent your code as a rule, for your own benefit and ours :)

Comment: ... Or have a look at the same question you asked a little while ago -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152435/how-to-stop-element-with-first-onclick-event-to-be-fired-when-enter-key-is-press/19154914#19154914

Comment: it worked tankx @pebbl

Comment: Then you should accept pebbl's answer on your othethat question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input  type="image" src='Create.gif' onclick="alert('not done'); return false;">
```

Comment: It's not possible i want the result when i click on it

Answer (score 0):

If the image is focused it will trigger the onclick event when you hit enter. Then you get two alert boxes popping up: the handleEnter of the div and the onclick of the image.